# Cron Job Running Shell Script to Run Python Not Working

Tags: bash, python-2.7, cron

As written in the title, I am having some problem with my cron job script not executing. I am using CentOS 7.

My crontab -e looks like this:

```
30 0 * * * /opt/abc/efg/cron_jobs.sh >> /opt/abc/logs/cron_jobs.log
```

My cron_jobs.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#keep this script in efg folder
#run this daily through crontab -e
#45 0 * * * /opt/abc/efg/cron_job.sh

cd "$(dirname "$0")"
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`

#some daily jobs script for abc
date

#send email to users whose keys will expire 7 days later
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 scripts/send_expiration_reminder.py -d 7
#send email to key owners whos keys will expire
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 scripts/send_expiration_reminder.py -d -1

# review user follow status daily task
# Need to use venv due to some library dependencies
/opt/abc/virtualenv/bin/python2.7 scripts/review_user_status.py
```

So, what I've found is that the log for the cron jobs in /var/logs/cron states that the cron ran at 0:30 am accordingly.

Strangely, I find that /opt/abc/logs/cron_jobs.log empty, and the scripts does not seem to run at all. It used to output some log before I re-inputted the crontab (to re-install the cron jobs), and replaced cron_jobs.sh, so I think the problem might have arose from those actions.

And also, I would like to know if there are any ways to log the error from executing a python script. I have been trying to run /opt/abc/virtualenv/bin/python2.7 scripts/review_user_status.py but it never seem to work as intended (does not run the main function at all), and there is no log output whatsoever.

I tried to run this on a different machine and it works properly, so I am not sure what is wrong with the cron job.

Here is a snippet of the log I got from /var/log/cron to show that the cron called the job:

```
Mar 22 18:32:01 web41 CROND[20252]: (root) CMD (/opt/abc/efg/cron_jobs.sh >> /opt/abc/logs/cron_jobs.log)
```

Comment: Add a command `set -x` to see what was started while the script was running

Comment: @Nigredon in the shell file? Like right below #!/bin/bash?

Comment: The funny thing is that I tried to run cron_jobs.sh using bash cron_jobs.sh, and it seems to work fine. But the diferrence is that I called chmod +x cron_jobs.sh before running bash.

Comment: Add `set -x` after `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: And how check cron job you can read in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42715/how-can-i-make-cron-run-a-job-right-now-for-testing-debugging-without-changing

Comment: When you needed to call `chmod +x cron_jobs.sh` before running bash, the missing execute right seems to be the problem that you fixed with the `chmod`.

Comment: @Nigredon `set -x` does not seem to change anything. My log is still empty even when it is called. Here is a snippet of the log I got from /var/log/cron `Mar 22 18:32:01 web41 CROND[20252]: (root) CMD (/opt/abc/efg/cron_jobs.sh >> /opt/abc/logs/cron_jobs.log)`

Comment: @WalterA can you elaborate on this? So are you saying that I should run `chmod +x cron_jobs.sh` everytime cron_jobs.sh is ran?

Comment: @stvin When you run `ls -l /opt/abc/efg/cron_jobs.sh`, you should see something like `-rwxr-xr-x` (an `x` for root and the owner). When this changes without you touching it, look at any automated jobs like `puppet` or `ansible` resetting the mode.

Comment: Does your script run properly under `env -i HOME=$HOME ./cron_jobs.sh`? If not, you have an environment problem, i.e. some environment variable is set in your login shell that is not set in your script. Remember, cronjobs get a tiny environment. Even PATH may not be what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few areas to check if you haven't performed these already,

1. if your executable permissions set on the script,
   `chmod +x <python file>`
   in addition permissions for the user to access the directories.
2. Run the script manually to test the script works from beginning to end, as the user who will be running the script, will be more realistic.
3. You can test your crontab schedule by temporarily setting every minute for testing, unlike Windows where you can right, click and click Run.

Comment: The cron job runs properly on different machine (I tried it by making a job using cron tab every minute as per your suggestion and it works fine), so I am not sure if it is the shell script problem or the crontab problem. Do you have any idea on how to determine this?

Comment: On the server which the script does not run, check your configuration is how you install the script on other servers. Check python is installed properly with the following command, `python -v` then as the user you want to run this cronjob, run the script manually. Without crontab, and check all output and the logs.

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you all for the suggestions and heads up. I found out that what was ruining my script is the existence of `/r` in the line break. Apparently, Linux in general does not accept `/r` and only accepts `/n`.

It is because I ftp my files to the machine where the script breaks. On the other hand, it works fine on another machine because I used `git pull` instead of ftp.

Hope that this info will also be a helpful to others!